# how to parse json nested dict in python?

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I'm trying to work with json file stored locally. That is formatted as below:

```
{  
   "all":{  
      "variables":{  
         "items":{  
            "item1":{  
               "one":{  
                  "size":"1"
               },
               "two":{  
                  "size":"2"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the value of the size key using the following code.

```
with open('path/to/file.json','r') as file:
  data = json.load(file)
itemParse(data["all"]["variables"]["items"]["item1"])

def itemParse(data):
   for i in data:
   # also tried for i in data.iterkeys():
       # data has type dict while i has type unicode
       print i.get('size')
       # also tried print i['size']
```

got different errors and nothing seems to work. any suggestions?

> also, tried using json.loads got error expect string or buffer

Comment: Use data[i]['size'] on your print line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you iterate over `data` you are getting the key only. There is 2 ways to solve it.

```
def itemParse(data):
   for i, j in data.iteritems():
       print j.get('size')
```

or

```
def itemParse(data):
   for i in data:
       print data[i].get('size')
```

Comment: Thanks Mauro! but I'm wondering why I can't get the same result if I print i.get('size')? without using data again as in your second example?

Comment: As I said in answer, when you iterate over a dict, it retrieves the key. So you are tring to use `get` method in a string.

Answer (score 0):

First, use `json.loads()`.

```
data = json.loads(open('path/to/file.json','r').read())
```

Second, your `for` loop should be changed to this

```
for k,v in data.iteritems():
    print data[k]['size']
```

Regarding the `error expect string or buffer`, do you have permissions to read the json file?